# How to create variables on the fly in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary and code, I want to concatenate the values of the dictionary, if the head and tail of the values are the same:

```
    import random

    dic={'1':[(1,2,4,3),(1,2,3,1)],'2':[(2,4,2,3),(2,6,5,3)],'3':[(3,5,9,1),(3,2,5,2),(3,7,8,1)]}

    c1= (1,2,4,3)
    c2=random.choice(dic[str(c1[-1])])
    c3=random.choice(dic[str(c2[-1])])
    c4=random.choice(dic[str(c3[-1])])
    c5=random.choice(dic[str(c4[-1])])
    print(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)
```

I get a result like this:
`(1, 2, 4, 3) (3, 5, 9, 1) (1, 2, 4, 3) (3, 2, 5, 2) (2, 4, 2, 3)`
The dictionary has the first element of the tuple as key, for the given `c1`, I use the last element of `c1` as key to get a random tuple from `dic`, by this way, I get `c2`,`c3`,`c4`,`c5`.
My question is: I want to write a function with integral input, which could be 10, or 20, so I could get `c10`, `c20` iteratively, not like now I must write every step of `c1`, `c2`,`c3`,`c4`,`c5`,`c6`....

Simply, how to create variables dynamically>

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question and description don't match... You want concatenation or dynamic variable creation?

Comment: Check this too; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: You just need the concatenation? I mean, for what I see you don't need to actually have c1, c2...cn but anything else than printing the final concatenation.

Comment: yes, I just need the concatenation, but the length of the concatenation should be variable, not just be 5 like in the example

Comment: Alright, I get it. Let me elaborate the answer with a possible solution

Comment: I think you should update the name of the question, by the way. "How to create variables on the fly in Python?" doesn't represent what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: thanks for the new name

Answer (score 0):

So far from understanding your question, I infer that you want an automated way to create variables on the fly, that is have `c<n>` variables without typing it on your own.

You have two methods:

1. Using `exec`:
   `exec` is used to execute Python code from the code itself. So you can try something like this:

```
inp = int(input('How many? ))
for i in range(inp):
    val = 20 # Enter the value here
    exec(f"c{i}=val")
```

But **this is not recommended**

2. Using dictionary:
   Dictionaries were meant for this and are perfect here

```
inp = int(input("How many? "))
vals = {}
for i in range(inp):
    val = 10 # Value
    vals[f"c{i}"] = val # or simply vals[i]
```

Comment: val = 10 is a constant, but for every c0, c1, c2, ...I need them to be different, and c1 is calculated depending on c0, c2 is calculated depending on c1, c3 is calculated depending on c2, ...usw

Comment: vals = {}
for i in range(inp):
    if i==0:
        vals[f"c{0}"] = (1,2,4,3)
    #i>0    
    else:
        vals[f"c{i}"] = random.choice(dic[str(vals[f"c{i-1}"][-1])])

Answer (score 0):

I think using recursion is a nice approach to solve this.

```
import random

def concatenator(dictionary, i, key=1):
    if i > 0:
        tuple_chosen = random.choice(dictionary[str(key)])
        next_key = tuple_chosen[-1]
        return str(tuple_chosen) + concatenator(dictionary, i-1, key=next_key)
    else:
        return ""
```

Using this function as follows: (i is the number of tuples you want to have at the end)

```
dic = {'1': [(1,2,4,3),(1,2,3,1)],
       '2': [(2,4,2,3),(2,6,5,3)],
       '3': [(3,5,9,1),(3,2,5,2),(3,7,8,1)]}

concatenator(dic, 5)
# outputs: '(1, 2, 3, 1)(1, 2, 3, 1)(1, 2, 3, 1)(1, 2, 3, 1)(1, 2, 3, 1)'
```

Comment: very nice and fancy 

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a list comprehension using the assignment expression operator `:=` in Python 3.8.

```
>>> import random
>>> dic={'1':[(1,2,4,3),(1,2,3,1)],'2':[(2,4,2,3),(2,6,5,3)],'3':[(3,5,9,1),(3,2,5,2),(3,7,8,1)]}
>>> y = (1,2,4,3)
>>> n = 20
>>> [(y:=random.choice(dic[str(y[-1])])) for _ in range(n)]
[(3, 2, 5, 2), (2, 4, 2, 3), (3, 7, 8, 1), (1, 2, 4, 3), (3, 2, 5, 2), (2, 4, 2, 3), (3, 7, 8, 1), (1, 2, 4, 3), (3, 5, 9, 1), (1, 2, 3, 1), (1, 2, 3, 1), (1, 2, 3, 1), (1, 2, 4, 3), (3, 2, 5, 2), (2, 4, 2, 3), (3, 7, 8, 1), (1, 2, 3, 1), (1, 2, 3, 1), (1, 2, 3, 1), (1, 2, 4, 3)]
```

The initial choice of `y` doesn't really matter, as long as `str(y[-1])` is a key in `dic`.